# How to reuse member object's comparator

Tags: java, comparator

If there is a `StudentUnion` class that has a corresponding comparator defined, and when it becomes a member object of `Student` class, which wants to get sorted in collection with the same factor(sorted by student union), then how to avoid re-coding another  comparator which almost does the same job as the `StudentUnionComparator`? Is there a best design of such situation?

```
public class Student{
    ....
    private StudentUnion;
    ....
}

public class StudentUnionComparator implements Comparator<StudentUnion>{
    public int compare(StudentUnion s1, StudentUnion s2){
        ....
        return result // 1 or 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass in an instance of `StudentUnionComparator`?

Comment: Make your `Student` class implements `Comparable<Student>` and use an instance of your `StudentUnionComparator` to implement the `compareTo` method.

Comment: Thanks Rohit Jain & Luiggi Mendoza. So at least a new comparator is not avoidable?

Comment: Unless you want to make a `Map<StudentUnion, List<Student>>` where you'll sort the keys with your `StudentUnionComparator` and than add each element of each `Student` list. Quite the pain compared to (pun intended) another comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `StudentUnion` implement `Comparable`:

```
public class StudentUnion implements Comparable<StudentUnion> {

    public int compareTo(StudentUnion s) {
        ....
        return result // 1 or 0;
    }
}
```

then have `Student` implement `Comparable` too, using the `StudentUnion` first, then some other attribute second in case `StudnetUnion` compares the same:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        int result = studentUnion.compareTo(s.studentUnion);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        // use another field like name to break ties on StudentUnion
        return name.compareTo(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to create a `Comparator` for your `Student` class where you'll use the `StudentUnion` instance that it holds to compare with.

List this :

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
  public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
    return s1.getStudentUnion().compareTo(s2.getStudentUnion();
    }
  }
```

Edit : That gives you the flexibility to code another way to sort your `Student` in the same `StudentUnion`. Like Bohemian's answer with the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object instant of StudentUnion. Object will accept all classes.

```
public class CommonComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    public int compare(Object s1, Object s2){
        ....
        return result // 1 or 0;
    }
}
```